# Mogrify Adding 'x-x' to file

Tags: linux, mogrify

After running the following command for a directory that contains just original.tif

mogrify -auto-orient -format jpg -thumbnail 800x524 -write /var/www/photos/assets/output/12923/800.jpg /var/www/photos/assets/output/12923/original.tif

The following is generated, e.g. three files not named what they should be.

```
root@server:/var/www/photos/assets/output/12923# ls -ahl
total 11M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4.0K Dec 12 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2.1M Dec  7 02:49 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    123K Dec 12 11:09 800-0-0.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     53K Dec 12 11:09 800-0-1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     53K Dec 12 11:09 800-1.jpg
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 7.6M Apr 23  2003 original.tif
```

How to I get the command to work as it should?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the TIF has three different layers. Instead run:

mogrify -auto-orient -format jpg -layers flatten -thumbnail 800x524 -write /var/www/photos/assets/output/12922/800.jpg /var/www/photos/assets/output/12922/original.tif

https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18978